# Un numero muy grande no me cabe en un int

Tags: c++, string, números-enteros

Tengo problemas con un código, necesito guardar un numero de 12 dígitos pero no me deja, llega un momento en el que a medida que voy incrementando el numero cuando llega a 9 dígitos, empieza a mostrarme números negativos.
Aquí les dejo el código, la cosa es que voy tomando los números de un `string` y se lo sumo a una variable a la cual la voy multiplicando por 10.

Ya probé usando un `long long` y un `unsigned long long` para `Y` y no me a funcionado.

```
bool sustitucionserial(string b,int y) {
    string c;
    int p;
    int aux;
    for (int i=1;i<12;i++) {
        c=b[i];
        p=atoi(c.c_str());
        y=y*10;
        y=y+p;
        cout<<y<<endl;
    }
    y=y%9;
    if(y==8) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Por cierto la variable Y, por defecto ya tiene un numero de 2 digitos, tipo 22 o 10, y a ese numero le agrego 11 digitos mas entonces son 13 digitos en total

Comment: En inglese, pero podria [interesarte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568446/the-best-cross-platform-portable-arbitrary-precision-math-library).

Answer (score 1):

Ya descubri el problema, el tipo de dato long long no me servia pues cuando llamaba a la funcion lo hacia de la manera void nombre(int c) entonces me transformaba el long long a un int

Answer (score 0):

Hola Buenas mira te explico, si no puedes usar tu variable de tipo int, por que no usas la misma variable pero de tipo char a int ?
te dejo una referencia muy buena que encontré!:

```
char <identificador> []= "120398320948309582309840932840923840932840928409328";
float numero;
numero =atof(identificador);
cout<<numero<<end1; 
getch();
return 0;
```

[Link a Youtube con Video Explicativo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNc_WK7-G7s)

Comment: `float` (y tambien `double`) no es preciso, vas a perder dígitos!

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la arquitectura -en particular lo que se conoce como *tamaño de palabra* en bits: 8, 16, 32 ó 64- cada tipo de dato tiene límites; de tal manera que si revisas el **tamaño del tipo de dato** encontrarás que el valor máximo que almacena el tipo `int` es típicamente de 10 dígitos, por eso puedes notar inconsistencia después del noveno. Dependiendo de la versión de C y la arquitectura, si esta disponible puedes esar el tipo `long long int` en **ambos operandos**, de lo contrario pueden ocurrir **conversiones aritméticas**.

Comment: Mejor: Utiliza unos de los tipos de cabecera `cstdint` (por ejemplo `uint64_t`). Asi siempre se sabe cuantos bits estan disponible.